# swapImage {src: ‘image2.jpg’} doesn't respond in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm in the midst of upgrading my Rails app from 2.3 to 3.2, but I'm stuck on 3.1 at the moment.

I'm currently struggling with converting references to image filenames into a syntax that works with the asset pipeline. The main place I need with help with this issue is with my button rollover swapImage statements. Here's an example:

```
<%= image_submit_tag "signin.jpg", {:class => "swapImage { src: '#{image_path('signinHover.jpg')}' }" %>
```

This works in development. But when I deploy this code to production, the rollover still doesn't work. I get no apparent rollover response at all. Also, the single quote still appears escaped when I view source:

```
<input class="swapImage {src: &#x27;/assets/signinHover.jpg&#x27;}" src="/assets/signin.jpg" type="image" />
```

I'm guessing this might be part of my problem.

I'm also wondering if perhaps I'm not loading my javascript/jquery assets correctly using the asset pipeline. But when I check https://staging.genlighten.com/assets/application.js, I see the swapImage code appearing just fine.

I'd appreciate advice on how to implement swapImage correctly in Rails 3.1, with the proper syntax for images served by the asset pipeline. Alternatively, is there a better approach to rollover button images that I should use instead?

Thanks very much,

Dean Richardson 
Genlighten.com

Comment: Why are you placing what appears to be a json object inside of a css class? That is EXTREMELY odd architecture.

Comment: Is rails supposed to output an image path there before sending this as html output?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things need fixing here.
First off, you have a src attribute on an input tag. Those two things don't mix.
You'll need to be styling your input with CSS or putting an image element in there somewhere to make this work.

Since you're looking to have an on-hover image switch effect, I would suggest using CSS sprites. Loading an image once the mouse is over the target is going to break user experience because until the browser manages to load the content your button will *disappear completely*.

Check out one of the ten million bajillion css sprites tutorials out there, like this one (first one I found on the Goog):

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Now. If you're set on putting an alternate source in the tag itself and loading that on hover, I would suggest you put it in a data-attribute:

```
<img class="swapImage" data-image-swap="{src: &#x27;/assets/signinHover.jpg&#x27;}" src="/assets/signin.jpg" />
```

Note this is an image tag, not an input. You'll have to add the input in there somewhere :/

Can you post the code that you're looking to output? Also, it'd be good to include your swapImage() method so we can look at that.

Again, using javascript to make hover effects happen is BAD PRACTICE. I HIGHLY SUGGEST you go with sprites.

Highly. :)